# How To Make Code for BackgroundWorker Events in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, backgroundworker

In **VB.Net** after I declare the variable `BackgroundWorker` I have access to the events. When I click on it, the event function is created:

[image]

**But in C# does not have that option.** How can I create the function signature for those events in Visual Studio? Do I have to do it by hand?

[image]

Comment: Type `bgWorkker1.RunWorkerCompleted += ` and it'll offer to autocomplete.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Ok, that work. But I think is unfair they hide it like that. I guess still have to learn new stuff.

Comment: You can also find event definitions in the `Properties Window`. See this for more info: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s9p2.html

Comment: @VisualVincent I can access `Property Window` of a button on the design window. But how I access when I declare it on code?

Comment: You can't, sorry about that... I wasn't reflecting that you declared the BGWs in code.

Comment: @VisualVincent I drag and drop backgroundWorker in the Form instead declare in the code, now I can access property ;)

Comment: The only thing that ever changes is the EventArgs (with standard items).  You can copy that from Object Browser

Comment: @Plutonix Dont know what you mean? I was trying to create the event signature. In vb I just double click and the signature was created.

Comment: Standard event signatures are all the same: `object sender, eventargs e`.  All you need to know is the `e`.  You can copy/paste that from Object Browser

Comment: @Plutonix Ok, Is good to know, but still would need assign the function to the event handler. So for this case is better just create the object on the form so  UI handles  all those things for you. Thanks

Comment: can downvoter explain why this is a bad question?

Comment: @vbnet3d Isnt duplicated, because in this case I create the object on the code instead of putting on the form. Of course I solve it putting the object on the form to have access to the `Property Window` but as you can see in the picture on VB you dont have to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an event handler in code in C# then you just start typing and then let the IDE generate the rest for you when it prompts, e.g.

```
myBackgroundWorker.DoWork +=
```

Once you get that far, Intellisense should kick in and offer to help.  It will first offer to finish that statement and then offer to create the event handler.

That said, I would always tend to use the designer if possible.  As suggested elsewhere, you can then use the Properties window, after clicking the Events button.  That same option is available in VB.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of declare the object in the code, I drag and drop from the tools to the form and now can use the property window to access the events

**ToolBox:**

[image]

**Property Window / Events:**

[image]

Comment: can downvoter explain why this is a bad answer? To access properties you need to put the object in the form instead declare it on code.